# Copying data from one table into another postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

So I have one table with duplicates of data and I only want to copy the distinct rows into the new table and also give the new table primary key id. This is what I have so far but it doesn't seem to do what I want it to.

```
INSERT INTO m_new
SELECT * FROM m
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT DISTINCT address, city, zip FROM m
)
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.  Your query is confusing.  What is `m`?  What is `mm`?

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure you want `distinct on`:

```
INSERT INTO m_new
    SELECT DISTINCT ON (address, city, zip) m.*
    FROM m
    ORDER BY address, city, zip;
```

`DISTINCT ON` returns one row for each group of keys.